# Hyper-V virtual network adapter's are assigned physical interface's mac

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, hyper-v, mac-address, hardware-virtualization

I am having trouble with hyper-V to force it to use the actual mac address of the virtual network adapter when packets from these virtual interfaces leave the physical network adapter,

I've two virtual network adapters of-course both having different mac-addresses, but when I analyze the physical network interface (interface which I've used to create these virtual network adapters) using wireshark
I can see that both IP addresses assigned to the virtual network adapters use the same mac address as the physical network interface's mac address,

My question is how can I force the packet's to have the same mac address as the virtual network adapter's mac instead of the physical network adapter's mac when they leave the physical interface?

Answer (score 0):

You could [change the mac address](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-change-mac-address/) of your network card in device manager (assuming it supports it but most do) but this might cause issues probably the best way would be to do that and to have all the VMs and the host connected to a internal network then get to the host to act as a gateway for the VMs using the windows server routing role in a NAT setup, [here](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/HOW10169/configuring-windows-server-2012-r2-as-a-router?lang=EN) is a good guide to set that up on 2012r2

[This](https://serverfault.com/questions/462178/duplicate-mac-address-on-the-same-lan-possible) posts answer has a good explanation of why having two devices with the same mac would be bad although as one would be a virtual device internal to the hyper-v host i'm not sure if it would apply.